# Personalizar rango en filtro por precio en Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, cms

Alguien sabe como poner un rango personalizado para los precios en el bloque de navegación por facetas, mi actual filtro el que viene en le tema por defecto toma el valor mínimo y máximo y lo divide en 4 rangos. Estoy usando Prestashop 1.6.1.4.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que necesito es yo mismo poner mi rango de precios y al costado el checkbox como en los demás filtros seria algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y algo que me di cuenta es que al seleccionar varios rangos de precios no se acumulan a diferencia de los otros filtros que si lo hacen por la función de checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de la Configuración del Modulo, te recomiendo que quites esa opcion de checkbox y lo hagas por slider es mucho mas funcional

1) Ir a : Modulos > Bloque Navegación de Facetas 
2) Selccionar Template abajo

Aqui deja el valor Deslizador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al final quedará así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]